# Error when executing ping command

Tags: bash

host.txt:

```
www.google.com
```

test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
    echo $line
    echo "#1"
    ping -c 1 $line
    line2="www.google.com"
    echo "#2"
    ping -c 1 $line2
done < $hostfile
exit 0
```

---

output:

```
> test.sh
www.google.com
#1
ping: unknown host www.google.com
#2
PING www.google.com (74.125.206.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wk-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.206.147): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=22.1 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.111/22.111/22.111/0.000 ms
```

Could someone tell why first ping failed?

Thanks.

Comment: Other than the obvious?

Comment: Does you name resolver work?

Comment: @Michael yes ping www.google.com works perfectly

Comment: Have you tried to execute `ping www.google.com` from the command prompt...?

Comment: Possibly your txt file contains CRLF line endings and bash actually tried to ping `www.google.com^M` name...?

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. This is exactly the reason. dos2unix solved the pb.

Comment: If it solved the problem, it deserves to be an answer. Posted  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856382/733637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly your txt file contains CRLF line endings
and bash actually tried to ping `www.google.com^M` name.